# ServiceProxy throws ProtocolException, communication is not restored on retrying

Tags: azure-service-fabric

We are seeing ProtocolExceptions while communicating with a service running in the cluster. The message and InnerException message:

```
System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException: You have tried to create a channel to a service that does not support .Net Framing.
---> System.IO.InvalidDataException: Expected record type 'PreambleAck', found '145'.
```

This service is running on a local dev cluster, and the exception is thrown after communicating successfully with the service.

The code that we use for communicating is:

```
var eventHandlerServiceClient = ServiceProxy.Create<IEventHandlerService>(eventHandlerTypeName, new Uri(ServiceFabricSettings.EventHandlerServiceName));
return await eventHandlerServiceClient.GetQueueLength();
```

We have retry logic (with increasing delay's between the attempts). But this call never succeeds. So it looks like the service is in a fault state and cannot recover from it.

**Update**

We are also seeing the following errors in the logs:

```
connection 0x1B6F9EB0 localhost:64002-[::1]:50376 target 0x1B64F3C0: invalid frame: length=0x1000100,type=514,header=28278,check=0x742E7465
```

**Update 14-12-2015**

If this ProtocolException is thrown, retries don't help. Even after hours of waiting, it still fails.

We log the endpoint address with

```
var spr = ServicePartitionResolver.GetDefault();
var x = await spr.ResolveAsync(new Uri(ServiceFabricSettings.EventHandlerServiceName), 
        eventHandlerTypeName, 
        new CancellationToken());
var endpointAddress = x.GetEndpoint().Address;
```

The resolved endpoint looks like

```
{"Endpoints":{"":"net.tcp:\/\/localhost:57999\/d6782e21-87c0-40d1-a505-ec6f64d586db\/a00e6931-aee6-4c6d-868a-f8003864a216-130945476153695343"}}
```

This endpoint is the same as reported by the Service Fabric Explorer.

From our logs seen, it seems that this service is working (it is reachable via another API method), but this specific call never succeeds.

Answer (score 1):

This typically indicate mismatched communication stack on the service and client side. Once the service is up and running, check the endpoint of the service replica via Service Fabric Explorer. If that seems fine, check that the client is connecting to the right service. Resolve the partition using the ServicePartitionResolver (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.servicefabric.services.servicepartitionresolver.aspx), passing the same arguments that you pass to ServiceProxy.

Comment: We are stilling testing and gathering the information. As soon as we have traces we will report back.

Comment: Hi @VipulM-MSFT ,  I've added some extra information.

Answer (score 1):

I'm seeing the same sort of errors. Just looking at my code, I'm caching an actorproxy. I'm going to change that and remove the caching in case the cache is referencing an old instance of the service.

That appears to have fixed my issues. I'm guessing that the proxy caches the reference once it has been used and if the service changes, that reference is out of date.